# install node.js using gcloud on Google Compute Engine

Tags: node.js, google-compute-engine, gcloud, google-cloud-console

I need to install node.js using https://developers.google.com/deployment-manager/nodejs.

when I create template using gcloud I get

> "message": "The user does not have write permission for project
>   XYZprojectname."

I tried Google Cloud Deployment Manager API under APIs and AUTH but getting the same message again and again.

Billing is enabled for the project.
Please let me know what I am missing here..

Regards,
Shashank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure you have enable [Google cloud Deployment Manager](https://developers.google.com/deployment-manager/sign-up), note that this is currently in limited preview, so you need to request access to the service before you can use it.
2. You also need to enable the [command-line-tool](https://developers.google.com/deployment-manager/commandline-tool#starting).
3. Run the script google-cloud-sdk/install.sh, authenticate using 'gcloud auth login' and configure your project with 'gcloud config set project PROJECT-ID' and enable the preview features with 'gcloud config set project PROJECT-ID'

The authentication process will help you with the issue related to permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You find very detailed tutorials on how to set up nodejs using gcloud on Google Compute Engine Services here:

https://developers.google.com/deployment-manager/commandline-tool
https://developers.google.com/deployment-manager/nodejs